# вложенное значение span

Tags: javascript

html

```
<span id="price">4500</span>
```

JS

```
var price = document.getElementById('price').innerHtml;
```

вопрос в том, почему значение переменной `undefined`, либо если использовать `parseInt`, то же самое

Answer (score 5):

Потому что свойство называется не `innerHtml`, а `innerHTML`. *JavaScript* - регистрозависимый язык.